# Windows 7 UEFI: Help bcdedit find the "default" store in the EFI partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, uefi

`bcdedit` and similar tools[1] can't find where the store is. It's in the EFI system partition and I have to manually mount and assign a letter, then work on it with `/store`. Is there a "setting" that allows `bcdedit.exe` to point to a specific store, through a GUID or some other obscure means?

OR, is the system store "referenced" after booting Windows 7 UEFI?

[1] `msconfig.exe` for example, does not do anything in the "Boot" tab. I literally can't select anything.

I'm asking this question because I feel this is the root of my problems with hibernation. Also to help other people who *still* use Windows 7.

**Edit:**

I just tried changing the GPT partition attributes of my EFI system partition from 0x8000000000000000 to 0x8000000000000001. Will let you notify if it works on my next reboot.

**Edit 2:**

Yeaaah it didn't do anything. Maybe I'll try doing 0x0000000000000000 next, allow drive automounting?

Comment: " I have to manually mount and assign a letter, then work on it with /store" is this what you are trying to work around, so you do not have to do this?

Comment: Yes exactly! Sorry if I haven't clarified it. I also think it's the source of another problem: hibernation going directly to the lock screen, as I believe the OS can't find the entry for hibernation?

Comment: I have an idea which I do NOT want to try at the current moment: Should I remove the GPT attribute "GPT_BASIC_DATA_ATTRIBUTE_NO_DRIVE_LETTER" of the EFI System Partition? That *should* allow it to mount? I do NOT want to try this unless someone already did.